# Binary search basic . Stuck in an Infinite loop

Tags: java, sorting, search, binary

im trying to implement a basic form of binary search. i created an array and filled out with linear values. Now just trying to sort through it to find a number and its index.. The problem is that it is getting stuck in a constant loop and returning zero. it goes through the nested loop because it prints but is unable to find the target value. Below is the code

```
for (int i= 1; i < 10000 ; i++){
        studentID[i] = i;
    }
   Students studentIDNumber = new Students();
   studentIDNumber.binarySearch(studentID, 400);


public void binarySearch(int[] studentID, int targetID){
    System.out.println("helloworld");
    int position = -1;
    int suspect;
    int suspectIndex = 0;
    int lastSuspectIndex = studentID.length-1;
    while(position == -1)
    {
        assert(suspectIndex<lastSuspectIndex);
        suspectIndex = ((studentID.length-1)/2);
        lastSuspectIndex =suspectIndex;
        suspect=studentID[suspectIndex];
        System.out.println(suspect);
        if(suspect == targetID){
            position = suspectIndex;
            System.out.println(suspectIndex +" is where the ID #"+targetID+" is sotred");
            break;
        }
         if(suspect < targetID){
            suspectIndex= suspectIndex+(suspectIndex/2); 
             position = -1;
            }
         if(suspect > targetID){
            suspectIndex= suspectIndex-(suspectIndex/2); 
            position = -1;}
        else {
            System.out.println("ID not found " );   
            }
    }

 }
```

Comment: your problem starts with the statement 
lastSuspectIndex =suspectIndex;

1,2,3,4,5,6,7
now dry run the code and you would get that if TargetID>SuspectID
it must be suspectId=SuspectId+(SuspectID/2);

Comment: You are resetting `suspectIndex` back to half the length every loop. It's examining the same position every time which is why it never exits. You should put the first initialisation outside the loop. Unfortunately there are lots of other problems in the code (e.g if `suspectIndex` is 7500 and is too small then it will become 7500 + 7500 / 2 which will then be out of bounds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
  suspectIndex = ((studentID.length-1)/2);
```

suspectIndex will be the same for every loop iteration. Initialize the variable once before the loop but not at the start of the loop itself.

Comment: yup that was the major glitch. though now it can only find odd number targets. Im trying to see if that can be fixed ! thanks